# How to load model with Codeigniter Webservice - Nusoap Server?

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, nusoap

I am trying to load a model to a webservice (Nusoap) as follows:

Controller:

```
class Addition extends CI_Controller{
public function Addition(){
    parent::__construct();
    $ns = base_url().'addition/';
    $endpoint = base_url().'addition/';
    $this->load->library("nusoap_library"); // load nusoap toolkit library in controller
    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server(); // create soap server object
    $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("SMS SOAP", $ns, $endpoint); // wsdl cinfiguration
    $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns; // server namespace

    // REGISTER FUNCTIONS
    $input_array = array ('var1' => "xsd:string", 'var2' => "xsd:string"); // "addnumbers" method parameters
    $return_array = array ("var3" => "xsd:int", 'var4' => "xsd:string");
    $this->nusoap_server->register('send', $input_array, $return_array, "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$ns."send", "rpc", "encoded", "My Addition WS");
}

function index(){
    function send($var1, $var2){
        $this->load->model('mymodel'); // THIS IS MY MODEL

        $data['var1'] = $this->mymodel->addnumbers($var1, $var2);
        $data['var2'] = "yes";

        return $data;
    }

    $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
}
```

}

The problem is that if I take out the model and just add directly, it will work perfectly, but with the model it returns nothing.

Any help will be greatly appresiated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own question.

Apparently you cannot invoke directly the model. A way to do it is the following:

```
class Addition extends CI_Controller{
    public function Addition(){
    parent::__construct();
    $ns = base_url().'addition/';
    $endpoint = base_url().'addition/';
    $this->load->library("nusoap_library"); // load nusoap toolkit library in controller
    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server(); // create soap server object
    $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("SMS SOAP", $ns, $endpoint); // wsdl cinfiguration
    $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns; // server namespace

    // REGISTER FUNCTIONS
    $input_array = array ('var1' => "xsd:string", 'var2' =>  "xsd:string"); // "addnumbers" method parameters
    $return_array = array ("var3" => "xsd:int", 'var4' => "xsd:string");
    $this->nusoap_server->register('send', $input_array, $return_array, "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:".$ns."send", "rpc", "encoded", "My Addition WS");
}

function index(){
    function send($var1, $var2){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('mymodel'); // THIS IS MY MODEL

        $data['var1'] = $CI->mymodel->addnumbers($var1, $var2);
        $data['var2'] = "yes";

        return $data;
    }

    $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
}
```

I know this may not be the best solution but it works perfectly and you are able to load any model using Codeigniter Framework with Nusoap.

Hope this helps as future reference.

If anyone has a better way to load the model please let us know.